# I cloned a failing HDD on the WRONG target disk

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, ddrescue

I accidentally cloned a failing external HDD on the wrong target drive using the

```
ddrescue -d -f /dev/sdSource /dec/sdTarget
```

command.

Is there any way to recover anything from the target drive ?

The target drive is 1 TB the failing external drive was only around 250 MB. The back up drive I used appears now as the external drive I tried to save (same name, same capacity). How do I get back my 1 TB drive?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to recover anything from the target drive ?

No; anything that's been overwritten (i.e., the min(size(/dev/sdSource), size(/dev/sdTarget)) is gone. For good.